How to close dialog in Angular using ng Matero Extension?
In Angular, how can I close this dialog?
I'm unable to find a solution.
import { MtxDialog } from '@ng-matero/extensions/dialog';

  openAddUserModal() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.originalOpen(AddUsersComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { SubmitClose: true }
      
    });
  
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
      if (result === 'success') {
        this.fetchData(this.pageIndex, this.pageSize);
      }
    });
  }

I tried  this angular material it's work:
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
but I want  this:
import { MtxDialog } from '@ng-matero/extensions/dialog';


Did you try invoking open() instead of originalOpen() and setting the showCloseIcon property to true?

yes but if i use simple mat dialog its work but   materio its not worked
